# Search file using box api

Tags: box-api

> Can I able to search a file belong to particular folder Id using box V2 API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to scope a search through the API – it's always across the entire account. However, File name, description, and contents (if the user has an account including that) are indexed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. May I know will this feature be added in future ?

Comment: It's under consideration but has no definitive timeline at this point.